# How to have different gradle.properties files for release/debug builds?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We need to have `gradle.properties` files with different configs for release and debug builds, because some of the features we use are experimental and they break some things. Is that possible?

Example of our `gradle.properties` file

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
org.gradle.parallel=true
kotlin.incremental=true
android.enableD8=true
```

Answer (score 1):

**As per official document:**

You can create and configure build types in the module-level build.gradle file inside the android block. When you create a new module, Android Studio automatically creates the debug and release build types for you. Although the debug build type doesn't appear in the build configuration file, Android Studio configures it with debuggable true. This allows you to debug the app on secure Android devices and configures APK signing with a generic debug keystore.

You can add the debug build type to your configuration if you want to add or change certain settings. The following sample specifies an applicationIdSuffix for the debug build type, and configures a "staging" build type that is initialized using settings from the debug build type.

You can use same build.gradle for release and debug modes like:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
// Do whatever you want to do in release mode
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
// Do whatever you want to do in debug mode
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
        }

        /**
         * The `initWith` property allows you to copy configurations from other build types,
         * then configure just the settings you want to change. This one copies the debug build
         * type, and then changes the manifest placeholder and application ID.
         */
        staging {
            initWith debug
            manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"internal.example.com"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".debugStaging"
        }
    }
```

Ref: [Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#build-types)

Comment: How should I place these options: 
`org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
org.gradle.parallel=true
kotlin.incremental=true
android.enableD8=true`
from gradle properties?

Comment: Where you want to use this in debug or release mode?

Comment: I want to use it in debug mode

Comment: You can also set system properties in the gradle.properties file. If a property name in such a file has the prefix “systemProp.”, like “systemProp.propName”, then the property and its value will be set as a system property, without the prefix. In a multi project build, “systemProp.” properties set in any project except the root will be ignored. That is, only the root project’s gradle.properties file will be checked for properties that begin with the “systemProp.” prefix. Refer: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties

Comment: I see, so there is no way to separate it for debug/release except as the systemProp in command line? This should work but it is not very maintainable.

Answer (score -3):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
    debug1 {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    debug2 {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

You came different build variants like above and on Android studios select the build variants option(usually in the bottom left corner). select which variant you want to build the apk and run the app.